# Splitting a string text into separate rows and copy remaining columns down

Tags: excel, vba

I have column A and B with multiple entries of data separated by ";".

Columns C to Y inclusive also hold data, but some columns may be blank.

I am trying to separate the data in each cell in Col A, using ";", insert a new line for each individual item and copy down the associated data from col B to Y.  Then do the same for Col B, copying down data from Col A and also Col C to Y.

I have found code but is restricted to copying down Col B.

```
Option Explicit

Sub splitcellsmodified()

  Dim InxSplit As Long
  Dim SplitCell() As String
  Dim RowCrnt As Long

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    RowCrnt = 1

    Do While True
      If .Cells(RowCrnt, "A").Value = "" Then
        Exit Do
      End If
      SplitCell = Split(.Cells(RowCrnt, "A").Value, ";")

      If UBound(SplitCell) > 0 Then
        .Cells(RowCrnt, "A").Value = SplitCell(0)
        For InxSplit = 1 To UBound(SplitCell)
          RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1
          .Rows(RowCrnt).EntireRow.Insert
          .Cells(RowCrnt, "A").Value = SplitCell(InxSplit)
          .Cells(RowCrnt, "B").Value = .Cells(RowCrnt - 1, "B").Value
        Next
      End If

      RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1

    Loop

  End With

End Sub
```

Starting point
[image: Starting point]

Expected result
[image: Expected result]

Comment: @tonyDallimore can you help, it was your code that i am trying to modify

Comment: The desired result will have more rows then the starting point. Therefore, it is best to use 2 different worksheets (one for input, and one for output).

Comment: You are already using a variable `RowCrnt ` for the input rows; You will also need a variable for your output rows.

Answer (score 0):

(**Please note:** This answer writes to a new sheet, rather than splitting the lines in the input screen)

Staying as close as possible to your code, I would get:

```
Option Explicit

Sub splitCellsModified()

  Dim InxSplitA As Long
  Dim InxSplitB As Long         'We want to split 2 cells rather than 1
  Dim SplitCellA() As String
  Dim SplitCellB() As String    'We want to split 2 cells rather than 1
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowOutput As Long
  Dim wsOutput As Worksheet

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Worksheets.Add              ' The new worksheet becomes the active sheet.
    Set wsOutput = ActiveSheet
    wsOutput.Name = "AfterSplitup"
    RowCrnt = 1
    RowOutput = 1

    Do While True
      If .Cells(RowCrnt, "A").Value = "" Then
        Exit Do
      End If
      SplitCellA = Split(.Cells(RowCrnt, "A").Value, ";")
      SplitCellB = Split(.Cells(RowCrnt, "B").Value, ";")

      For InxSplitB = LBound(SplitCellB) To UBound(SplitCellB)
        For InxSplitA = LBound(SplitCellA) To UBound(SplitCellA)
          wsOutput.Cells(RowOutput, "A").Value = SplitCellA(InxSplitA)
          wsOutput.Cells(RowOutput, "B").Value = SplitCellB(InxSplitB)
          .Rows(RowCrnt).Range("C1:Y1").Copy _
              Destination:=wsOutput.Rows(RowOutput).Range("C1:Y1")
          RowOutput = RowOutput + 1
        Next InxSplitA
      Next InxSplitB

      RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1

    Loop

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks you for the above fix. its great clean code! Makes sense to move to another sheet. I'm going to keep the new sheet permanently, rather than adding a new one each time, i'll clear it at the beginning of my overall macro. I believe just removing "worksheets.add" and add in an activatesheet line will do the trick!